# How is a strong retain cycle possible with async or static calls?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, strong-references

I am trying to grasp how I can recognize when a strong retain cycle is possible and requires me to use `[weak/unowned self]`. I've been burned by unnecessarily using `[weak/unowned self]` and the self was deallocated immediately before giving me a chance to use it.

For example, below is an async network call that refers to `self` in the closure. Can a memory leak happen here since the network call is made without storing the call it self into a variable?

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!) {
  (data, response, error) in
  self.data = data
)
```

Here's another example using the NSNotificationCenter, where a call can be made later asynchronously:

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(
        UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) {
            [unowned self] _ in
            self.refresh()
    }
```

My question is in what cases is a strong retain cycle possible? If I am making an asynchronous call or static call that references self in a closure, does that make it a candidate for `[weak/unowned self]`? Thanks for shedding any light on this.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell:

The retain cycle can happen in two cases.

**Case 1:**

When two instances hold a strong reference to each other. You have to solve this by marking one of them as weak.

**Case 2: (Which is related to your questions)**

If you assign a closure to a property of a class instance and the body of that closure captures the instance.

In your two examples, no need to use weak self at all as `NSNotificationCenter` nor `NSURLSession` are properties to your class instance. (Or in other meaning, you don't have strong references to them)

Check this example where I have to use weak self:

```
[self.mm_drawerController setDrawerVisualStateBlock:^(MMDrawerController *drawerController, MMDrawerSide drawerSide, CGFloat percentVisible) {

    if (drawerSide == MMDrawerSideRight && percentVisible == 1.0) {
        [weakself showOverlayBgWithCloseButton:YES];
    }
    else{

        [weakself hideOverlayBg];
    }
}];
```

I have a strong reference to `mm_drawerController` and I assign a closure to it right?. inside this closure I want to capture self. So the closure will have a strong reference to self !! which is a disaster. In that case you will have a retain cycle. To break this cycle, use weak self inside the closure.

Answer (score 1):

A retain cycle is a situation when two objects has a strong reference to each other.

[image]

You are working with static variables NSURLSession.sharedSession() & NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter() and as you may remember:

> A singleton object provides a global point of access to the resources
>   of its class...You obtain the global instance from a singleton class
>   through a factory method. The class lazily creates its sole instance
>   the first time it is requested and thereafter ensures that no other
>   instance can be created. A singleton class also prevents callers from
>   copying, retaining, or releasing the instance.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html

Your "self" instance (like the others) doesn't have a strong reference to singletons objects and its closures too, that's why you don't have to worry about retain cycle in your case.

Check this great article for more details:
https://digitalleaves.com/blog/2015/05/demystifying-retain-cycles-in-arc/